# shell_exec not working, perhaps because of special characters

Tags: php, special-characters, shell-exec

I have a command that i want to run from php

```
$shell = 'mysqldump -uuser -ppass --where="id>' . $larger .' and id<' . $smaller .'" view allasins | gzip -c | sshpass -p "pass2" ssh user2@host.com  \'cat>/home/user/domain.com/file.sql.gz\'';
$shell = escapeshellarg($shell); //this is not working, escapeshellcmd($shell) also not working
shell_exec($shell);
```

So, anyone know what is wrong with these codes? There is no error message, it simply does not work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`escapeshellcmd` so :

```
$Command = escapeshellarg($shell);
```

The usage for

```
escapeshellarg()
```

is to escape individual strings, for it to work within your example:

```
$shell = 'mysqldump -uuser -ppass --where="id>' . escapeshellarg($larger) .' and id<' . escapeshellarg($smaller) .'" view allasins | gzip -c | sshpass -p "pass2" ssh user2@host.com  \'cat>/home/user/domain.com/file.sql.gz\'';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, as i pointed out in the question, `escapeshellcmd` also does not work. I don't know how to debug this since there is no warning or error message.

Comment: `$smaller` and `$larger` are just 2 numbers, so i think there is not anything to escape these variables. I worry about the end of the first line where there is `'` character

Comment: @aye So your worrying about your escape syntax? the `'.`?

Comment: I just guess so. I absolutely have no clue about the reason. `shell_exec` works fine for my simple query `$shell = 'mysqldump -uuser -ppass --where="id>' . $larger .' and id<' . $smaller .'" view allasins > temp.sql`. But when i attach the later part, it does not work. The whole original command `mysqldump -uuser -ppass --where="id>0 and id<100" view allasins | gzip -c | sshpass -p "pass2" ssh user2@host.com  'cat>/home/user/domain.com/file.sql.gz'` works fine in the command line.

Comment: @aye Does the user you are running apache as have permission to run commands like this? and have correct write/read permissions in /home/user/domain.com/file.sql.gz?

Comment: Yeah, the first half of the command is to backup my database in my local computer, the second half is to upload the backup file to the remote server. In my computer i always use root user, in the remote server i have permission to write to that folder also (since when i run from terminal, a backup.sql.gz is created and uploaded to the remote server successfully.